# How secure is my javascript, how easily can it be exploited?

Tags: javascript, security

I'm trying to make this code as secure as possible are there any imediate flaws that jump out? I *think* I have it locked down pretty tightly, is there anything else you would implement?

```
  function CheckPin(){

    var str="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    var strId= document.form1.tbPin.value;

    var lenId=strId.length;

    var check=true;



    //if (lenId != 20)

    if (!(lenId ==20 || lenId == 10))

    {

        alert("You must enter a 20 or 10 digit pin number.");

        document.form1.tbPin.focus();

        return false;

    }

    else

    {

        //for(var i=0;i<20;i++)

        for(var i=0;i<lenId;i++)

         { 

            check=str.indexOf(strId.charAt(i));



            if(check == -1) 

            {

                alert("Do not use special characters.(e.g. @,#,&) ");

                document.form1.tbPin.focus();

                return false;

                break;

            }

            else 

            {

                 if (i ==19)

                 {

                    break;

                 }

            }

         }

    }



    if (document.form1.btnChecker.value == 1)

    {

     alert("The processing is in progress.");

     return false;

    }



    document.form1.btnChecker.value = 1;

    }

    </script>

    <script src="../JS/Tags.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../JS/Tags2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Tags.js:

```
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```

Tags2.js:

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-1376772-6"); pageTracker._initData(); pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

Comment: "How secure is my javascript" - what does that mean?

Comment: I know it's impossible to be 100% secure but what I guess I mean is...
Is it easily breakable or is there anything that stands out that I should fix?

Comment: You haven't told us your requirements. Anything is 100% secure without requirements.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to use this as an authentication method for a 'coupon code' of 10 or 20 characters. I want to make sure it's difficult enough for people to not inject their own code/bypass authentication.

Comment: The checks can be easily bypassed if javascript is turned off. That's why the answer below recommends doing the validation on the server. Validation isn't meant to prevent code injection though. That should be performed at the point the input is used. For example, if it is going into a database, use prepared statements instead of building SQL strings.

Comment: Ah I see. Someone could probably do something along the lines of 
javascript:checkPin = var check { return true; } :'( Time to do some reading on server-side authentication...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Critical calculations must not be done in the browser. Anything that you run in the browser is meant purely as a convenience for the user. Having said that, the validation you do via JavaScript in the browser should produce the same result as the one you have to do on the server anyway.